# Java program's memory usage is not accurate

Tags: java, memory, jvm, runtime

In my java application, I display the memory usage of the program. Unfortunately it is sporadic and is often wrong. My current code is

```
component.setText("Memory usage : "+((Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()) / 1024 / 1024) + "mb");
```

Sometimes, it returns the right value (Should be about 10-20mb), and sometimes it returns very strange values. This correlates with other java programs running (Netbeans in particular), but still manifests when nothing else is running. What is wrong with that statement? Is there a better way to get a more accurate representation of memory usage?

Comment: I am not sure, but it is because Garbage collector run randomly and free memory. You might want to run garbage collector before printing this program.

Comment: But it is completely WAY over the actual usage (20 compared to 500).GC wouldn't be the cause of _that_ much discrepancy.

Comment: Connect using VisuamVM and see if your number matches with VisuamVM graph. You can perform some quick profiling with that tool.

Comment: What are these "very strange values"? If they are 500 as noted above, what kind of -mx are you setting? To see how much is allocated based on the current need of the process compared to the max allowed heap, compare runtime.totalMemory() with runtime.maxMemory()

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem. Had to do with a stack overflow that wasn't enough to be caught as an exception, but enough to spike memory usage.